# Launching MSIL exe as a 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows

Tags: .net

I'd like to be able to distribute one version of an executable that a user can configure to run as either 32-bit or 64-bit.  The service would have a 32-bit host process that would read configuration and launch new processes as 32 or 64-bit.  What I haven't determined is how/if a executable targeted for Any CPU can be launched as a 32-bit process under 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes little sense.  If your app can run as a 32-bit process and doesn't need the extra virtual memory space then there's just no point in ever running it as a 64-bit process.

Nor can you easily control it.  It requires changing a value in the .exe header.  The Corflags.exe utility can do this, but you cannot distribute it.  Hacking the headers yourself is technically possible but *very* fugly.  The ultimate obstacle is that you don't typically have the write access that's required to modify the .exe file on a properly secured machine (ie UAC).  If you really, really need to do this then just deploy two copies of the .exe

Which you can do by writing a very puny bootstrapper .exe.  All it needs to do is Assembly.Load() the main .exe and call its Program.Main() method.  Build two versions of it.

Comment: I'm aware that it can be forced this way and that isn't workable.  For most purposes, 64-bit will be preferred but 32-bit might be necessary for some backwards compatibility scenarios.  Deploying 2 copies is the default position but I was hoping there was another way.

Comment: All you need is a very puny bootstrapper EXE.  It can Assembly.Load() the main EXE and call its Program.Main() method.

Comment: Thanks, Hans - this might be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to reflect this suggestion as I believe it is one others might find useful.

Comment: Minds thinking alike, I did while you posted that comment.

Comment: I forgot about CorFlags. Thanks, we have an internal app in our company and I'm going to distribute that with our service build and control 32/64 with config.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting Any CPU means that you are targeting the **build machine's** operating system.  So if your build machine is 32-bit, then Any CPU will build a 32-bit output, and if your build machine is 64-bit, then you will get a 64-bit output.  This has nothing to do with the machine you deploy to.

In order to achieve what you're looking to do, you will really need 2 copies of the exe, one as a 32-bit version and the other as 64-bit.  You can do this by setting the Target platform to 32-bit and 64-bit respectively.  Once again, if you target Any CPU, Visual Studio will pick up whichever OS is currently on the build machine.

Comment: Loading a Any CPU targeted library into a 32-bit process will build for 32-bit.  So a 64-bit machine *can* build 32-bit code.  I'm just wondering if it possible to force this in a new process.

Comment: That's my point, it will **build**, which means the output binary is going to be either 32-bit or 64-bit, never both.  So that being the case, how can you launch a 64-bit built binary as a 32-bit process?  The only way is to have both the 32/64 bit versions and launch either one per your configuration file.

Comment: MSIL is compiled to native code (32-bit or 64-bit) at runtime.  The problem is how to instruct a 64-bit OS which to build.  If the project is compiled as explicitly 32-bit or 64-bit, the runtime will respect that.  If loaded in a running process, it will try to use the same as the hosting process.  .NET binaries are compiled to MSIL so they can be run in any environment in principal.