# Windows Service won't run as a 32 bit process

Tags: windows, service, x86, 32-bit, wixsharp

I have a Windows Service, written in C# (.Net Framework 4.8) and installed using an installer built with WixSharp. The service needs to run as 32bit (because it references a COM component which needs to run in 32 bit).

I have tried the following:

- All projects in the solution (the service itself, any helper libraries, and the installer project) have only one configuration, which is 32 bit (x86).
- corflags tells me that the service executable requires 32 bit; I also set that explicitly once more. I.e. I run

```
corflags.exe /32bitreq+ <myservice.exe>
```

as well as

```
corflags.exe <myservice.exe>
```

which gives me:

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x3
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 1
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0
```

But still, when I start the service, it runs as a 64bit process on a 64bit Windows 10 laptop.

Note that all similar questions, e.g. [Forcing a .Net Windows service to run as 32-bit on a 64-bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079066/forcing-a-net-windows-service-to-run-as-32-bit-on-a-64-bit-machine)  and  [Launching MSIL exe as a 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479174/launching-msil-exe-as-a-32-bit-process-on-64-bit-windows) , all state you only need to run corflags.exe, but this obviously does not work.

Any idea?